# Multi Value DWORD Enum as One Function Argument C++

Tags: c++, enums, dword

I am unable to get this to work. I want to include two values in the first func arg spot(Color and Black).

It works fine with one arg in arg1:
    `func(arg_a::Color, 5);`

I tried the following variations in arg1 unsuccessfully:

`arg_a::Color || Black
 arg_a::Color && Black
 (arg_a::Color, arg_a::Black)
 DWORD test = arg_a::Color&&Black;`

The documentation I have is below:
arg_a
Type: DWORD

The arg_a can be one or more of the following values: 
Color 
White 
Black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encode two "enum values" in one, you'd normally use one bit for each value:

```
enum {
    Black = 0x01;
    White = 0x02;
    Color = 0x04;
}
```

Then you can combine them with bitwise operators:

```
call(Black|White);
// or perhaps easier to read
call(Black + White);
```

On the receiving end

```
call(int val) {
    if (val & Black) { ... }
    if (val & White) { ... }
```

Note this is pseudo code only.

Answer (score 0):

try DWORD(arg_a::Black, arg_a::Color) // predefined macro
or (arg_a::Black|arg_a::Color) // bitwise or

you are using logical operators but you need some bitwise operations to get this done.